# During Android's Room migration, it sets the value to 1 instead of using the default value of 0

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I run some migrating tests. All I want now is to create a new table with only one column set to a default value of 0:

```
@Entity
data class FirstLoad (
    @ColumnInfo("isFirstCreated", defaultValue = "0")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val isFirstCreated: Int = 0,
)
```

However when I run the test (shown below), the logs says: 'expected: 0 but was : 1'

The test itself:

```
@Test
    fun migration5To6(){

        var db = helper.createDatabase(DB_NAME,5).apply {
            execSQL("INSERT INTO user VALUES('testValue','testValue2','0','0')")
            close()
        }

        db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(DB_NAME,6, true, UserDatabase.migration5To6)
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO FirstLoad DEFAULT VALUES")

        val resultCursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM FirstLoad") 
        assertThat(resultCursor.moveToFirst()).isTrue()
        val isFirstCreatedIndex = resultCursor.getColumnIndex("isFirstCreated")
        assertThat(isFirstCreatedIndex).isNotNull()
        assertThat(isFirstCreatedIndex).isEqualTo(0)
        val value = resultCursor.getInt(isFirstCreatedIndex)
        assertThat(value).isEqualTo(0)
        resultCursor.close()
}
```

So, each line passes the test except `assertThat(value).isEqualTo(0)` even though `migration5To6` looks like this:

```
        val migration5To6 = object: Migration(5,6){
          override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
             database.execSQL(
             "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FirstLoad (isFirstCreated INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0)"
              )
           }
        }
```

What I did that helped:

I manually provided values for the `isFirstCreated` column

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO FirstLoad VALUES('0')")
```

Furthermore, I asked chat gpt many times and  it confirmed that my code is correct. There are no erros that would result in the creation of a value 1 for `isFirstCreated` .

Comment: I have to add that the test passes when I change assertThat(value).isEqualTo(0) to assertThat(value).isEqualTo(1), which, of course, doesn't make any sense, but it demonstrates that I have correctly implemented different code in various parts of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I want now is to create a new table with only one column set to a default value of 0:

A solution is to use `INSERT INTO firstload VALUES(0);`

**However**

The insertion of 1 (actually an SQLite generated value) is how SQLite works when a row is inserted using `INSERT DEFAULT VALUES` **AND** the COLUMN is defined using `INETGER PRIMARY KEY`.

This is because a column that is defined as **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** (i.e. an integer type annotated with `@PrimaryKey` when using Room) is a special handling situation where the column is in fact an alias of the normally hidden **rowid** column and in the absence of a value being provided will be 1 greater than the highest existing value of the column. In the case of no value existing then the generated value is 1.

It should be noted that `autoGenerate=false` does not turn off this feature. Rather it just turns off the inclusion of the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, a constraint(rule) that restricts the generated value to being a value that MUST be greater than any value ever used (even if rows have been deleted/updated).

Perhaps consider the following:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS firstload;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FirstLoad` (`isFirstCreated` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY(`isFirstCreated`));
INSERT INTO firstload DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO firstload DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO firstload DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO firstload VALUES(0);
SELECT rowid,* FROM firstload;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS secondload;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Secondload` (`isFirstCreated` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO secondload DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO secondload DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO secondload DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO secondload VALUES(0);
SELECT rowid,* FROM secondload;
/* Cleanup */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS firstload;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS secondload;
```

The first SELECT on the Firstload table results in:-

```
isFirstCreated  isFirstCreated(1)
0               0
1               1
2               2
3               3
```

- As can be seen the **rowid** column exists and the values exactly match the isFirstCreated column. They are in fact different ways of referencing that same (_*rowid* and also oid)

However, with secondload, where the isFirstCreated column is not defined using INTEGER PRIMARY then the results are:-

```
rowid   isFirstCreated
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       0
```

- As can be seen, as the `isFirstCreated` column is not defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then the default value of 0 has been set. However, the rowid is a generated value.

It makes little sense to specify a default value on a PRIMARY KEY, the value MUST be a UNIQUE value so there is a very good chance that utilising the default value will result in a UNIQUE conflict (unless of course if that column is also an INTEGER type).

Comment: Thank you, Mike, for the detailed response! It doesn't make almost any sense to set a default value for a primary key!  You completly answered my question! For my prroblem I think I'll create a table with only one row and 2 columns: Frist one is the primary key and the second one is just the value I want to keep during the app's life.